# How to find new limits by reversing order of integration in $\int_0^1\int_0^{\arccos(y)}x^2\sec(x)\,dx\,dy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have this integral:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\arccos(y)}x^2\sec(x)\,dx\,dy$$

When I reverse the order of integration, what will be its new limits? I think the new limits will be as following:

$0 \le y \le \cos(x)$  and  $0 \le x \le 1$

So,

1. Can someone tell me if I am correct
2. Is it possible if you can show shape of the region of integration and
   the orientation of the infinitesimal area elements for both the
   original and the reversed order of integration.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correct... the graphic of $x =\arccos y$ crosses the $x$-axis at $x =\pi/2$. So, the proper integration limits would be:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{\cos x} \frac{x^2}{\cos x} dy dx
$$

You should keep in mind that this is an improper integral.

Comment: Is it possible if you can show shape of the region of integration for these limit please, and how will they be different from the original integration function?

Comment: @EddieJames The region is exactly the same, it is just described in different ways.